# Bar chart label is missing when exceed certain width (since ExtJs 7.2)

Tags: extjs, extjs7

Ever since 7.2 , the label of the bar is pushed to the right and gone missing if the bar width is too long.

Initially, I override the redraw() function of CartesianChart to "shorten" the bar so that it will not take up 100% of the width and thus allow display of the label, like below:

```
attr = {
   visibleMinX: xRange[0],
   visibleMaxX: xRange[1],
   visibleMinY: yRange[0],
   visibleMaxY: yRange[1],
   innerWidth: innerWidth - 40, //leave 40px of "space"
   innerHeight: innerHeight,
   flipXY: flipXY
};
```

[image]

But since 7.2, the label was pushed towards right and gone missing. If you check here using 7.2.0 library, and press Play button, you will see the label "run" from right to left and disappear. Where as for prior version, the label remain on the right although in the below example, the label is not visible too because the bar width is too long. (if only I could fix this without the override code above)

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uea&view/editor

Somehow I'm able to capture the 90 while it's "moving" from right to left then disappear!
[image]

Comment: Anyone experience this before?

Comment: How can i control the width/length of the bar so that it will not fill up 100% in ExtJS 7?